# Aggregate function, group by clause error when summing difference between two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this large query I am working on:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#mappings') is not null drop table #mappings;
Create table #mappings
(
    GLEntity VARCHAR(MAX),
    NoteOwner VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #mappings
VALUES('351', 'Ajax E Master Trust I, a Delaware Trust, Wilmington Savings Fund Society, FSB, Trustee'),
('346', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2016-1, Mortgage-Backed Notes, Series 2016-1'),
('352', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2016-2, Mortgage-Backed Notes, Series 2016-2'),
('542', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2014-A, Mortgage-Backed Notes, Series 2014-A'),
('543', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2014-B, Mortgage-Backed Notes, Series 2014-B'),
('544', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2015-A, Mortgage-Backed Notes, Series 2015-A'),
('545', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2015-B, Mortgage-Backed Notes, Series 2015-B'),
('546', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2015-C, Mortgage-Backed Notes, Series 2015-C'),
('547', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2016-A, Mortgage-Backed Notes, Series 2016-A'),
('548', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2016-B, Mortgage-Backed Notes, Series 2016-B'),
('549', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2016-C, Mortgage-Backed Notes, Series 2016-C'),
('550', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2017-A, Mortgage-Backed Notes, Series 2017-A'),
('551', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2017-B, Mortgage-Backed Notes'),
('552', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2017-C, Mortgage-Backed Notes'),
('553', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2017-D, Mortgage-Backed Notes'),
('601', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2018-A Mortgage-Backed Notes'),
('602', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2018-B, Mortgage-Backed Notes'),
('557', 'Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2018-C, Mortgage-Backed Securities, Series 2018-C, by U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee'),
('557', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2018-C, Mortgage-Backed Securities, Series 2018-C'),
('603', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2018-D, Mortgage-Backed Securities, Series 2018-D'),
('603', 'Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2018-D, Mortgage-Backed Securities, Series 2018-D, by U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee'),
('604', 'Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2018-E, Mortgage-Backed Securities, Series 2018-E, by U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee'),
('604', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2018-E, Mortgage-Backed Securities, Series 2018-E'),
('605', 'Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2018-F, Mortgage-Backed Securities, Series 2018-F, by U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee'),
('605', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2018-F, Mortgage-Backed Securities, Series 2018-F'),
('606', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2018-F, Mortgage-Backed Securities, Series 2018-F'),
('608', 'Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2019-B, Mortgage-Backed Securities, Series 2019-B, by U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee'),
('607', 'Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2019-A, Mortgage-Backed Securities, Series 2019-A, by U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee'),
('607', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2019-A, Mortgage-Backed Securities, Series 2019-A'),
('609', 'Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2019-C, Mortgage-Backed Securities, Series 2019-C, by U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee'),
('609', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2019-C, Mortgage-Backed Securities, Series 2019-C'),
('561', 'Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2019-D, Mortgage-Backed Securities, Series 2019-D, by U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee'),
('561', 'U.S. Bank National Association, as Indenture Trustee on behalf of and with respect to Ajax Mortgage Loan Trust 2019-D, Mortgage-Backed Securities, Series 2019-D')


DECLARE @reportingDate date = '5/31/2019',
        @ArchiveDate date = '6/30/2019',
        @securitization VARCHAR(MAX) = '2018-B';

WITH RptPop AS
(
    SELECT 
     la.Account [LOAN_NBR]
    ,la.PmtPI [SCHED_P&I]
    ,la.NoteRate [NOTE_INT_RATE]
    ,la.NextDueDate [BORR_NEXT_PAY_DUE_DATE]
    ,la.PaidToDate [PIF_DATE]
    ,s.ActlBegPrinBal [ACTL_BEG_PRIN_BAL]
    ,s.SchedBegPrinBal [SCHED_BEG_PRIN_BAL]
    ,s.BeginNonInterestBearingDeferredPrincipal [BEGIN_NON_INTEREST_BEARING_DEFERRED_PRINCIPAL]
    ,s.Begin3rdPtyEscAdvanceBal [BEGIN_3RD_PTY_ESC_ADVANCE_BAL]
    ,s.BeginServicingEscAdvanceBal [BEGIN_SERVICING_ESC_ADVANCE_BAL]
    ,s.SchedGrossInterestAmt [SCHED_GROSS_INTEREST_AMT]
    ,s.NetIntRate [NET_INT_RATE]
    ,s.SchedNetInt [SCHED_NET_INT]
    ,s.ActlNetInt [ACTL_NET_INT]
    ,s.ActlEndPrinBal [ACTL_END_PRIN_BAL]
    ,s.SchedPrinamt [SCHED_PRIN_AMT]
    ,s.SchedEndPrinBal [SCHED_END_PRIN_BAL]
    ,s.LoanLossAmt [LOAN_LOSS_AMT]
    ,s.ActualEndingBalanceTotalDebtOwed [ACTUAL_ENDING_BALANCE_TOTAL_DEBT_OWED]
    ,s.EndingNonInterestBearingDeferredPrincipalBal [ENDING_NON_INTEREST_BEARING_DEFERRED_BAL]
    ,s.End3rdPtyEscAdvanceBal [END_3RD_PTY_ESC_ADVANCE_BAL]
    ,s.EndEscrowAdvanceBal [END_ESCROW_ADVANCE_BAL]
    ,la.NoteOwner
FROM esp.MARS_DW.dbo.vw_Loans_Archive la
LEFT JOIN esp.Securitization.dbo.SecuritizationReporting s on s.LoanNbr = la.Account
JOIN #mappings mp on mp.NoteOwner = la.NoteOwner
WHERE 
    la.ArchiveDate = @ArchiveDate 
    AND s.ReportingDate = @reportingDate
    AND la.NoteOwner LIKE '%2018-B%'
)

,
gl_entries_for_month AS
(
SELECT
a.name [Account]
,ac.AccountNo
,le.LocationID
,act.Code
,dd.Date
,CASE WHEN EntryType = -1 THEN fle.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END AS CreditAmount
,CASE WHEN EntryType = 1 THEN fle.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END AS DebitAmount
FROM DWH.GL.FactLedgerEntry fle WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN DWH.GL.DimJournals j WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON  j.JournalID = fle.JournalID
JOIN DWH.GL.DimAssets a WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON  a.AssetID = fle.AssetID
JOIN DWH.GL.DimAccounts ac WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON  ac.AccountID = fle.AccountID
JOIN DWH.GL.DimLocationEntity le WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON  le.LocationEntityID = fle.LocationID
JOIN DWH.GL.DimActivity act WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON  act.ActivityID = fle.ActivityID
JOIN DWH.dbo.DimDate dd WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON  dd.DateID = fle.BatchDateID
JOIN MARS.dbo.vw_Loans vl WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON  vl.Account = a.Name
WHERE   fle.EntryState = 'Posted'
        AND dd.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @ArchiveDate), 0) AND @ArchiveDate
)





SELECT

DISTINCT RptPop.[LOAN_NBR]

,CASE WHEN gl_entries_for_month.Code IN ('PMTI', 'SPYO', 'PMTO') 
        AND gl_entries_for_month.LocationID = mp.GLEntity 
        AND gl_entries_for_month.AccountNo IN ('18125','18130') 
        THEN SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount) ELSE 0 END AS [TEST]


FROM 

RptPop 

JOIN gl_entries_for_month on gl_entries_for_month.Account = RptPop.[LOAN_NBR]
LEFT JOIN #mappings mp on mp.NoteOwner = RptPop.NoteOwner and mp.GLEntity = gl_entries_for_month.LocationID

WHERE RptPop.LOAN_NBR = '######-513'

GROUP BY RptPop.LOAN_NBR
```

I am getting the error when at this part in the code:

```
CASE WHEN gl_entries_for_month.Code IN ('PMTI', 'SPYO', 'PMTO') 
        AND gl_entries_for_month.LocationID = mp.GLEntity 
        AND gl_entries_for_month.AccountNo IN ('18125','18130') 
        THEN SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount) ELSE 0 END AS [TEST]
```

I thought by adding GROUP BY RptPop.LOAN_NBR then I would not be getting these errors:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 121
Column 'gl_entries_for_month.Code' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 121
Column 'gl_entries_for_month.Code' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 121
Column 'gl_entries_for_month.Code' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 122
Column 'gl_entries_for_month.LocationID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 122
Column '#mappings.GLEntity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 123
Column 'gl_entries_for_month.AccountNo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 123
Column 'gl_entries_for_month.AccountNo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

I am pretty new to SQL if anyone knows how to help me I would greatly appreciate it. I tried to figure this out myself but I did not have any lunch researching the solution online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move `SUM` outside of the `CASE` statement:

```
SUM(CASE
       WHEN gl_entries_for_month.Code IN ('PMTI', 'SPYO', 'PMTO') 
        AND gl_entries_for_month.LocationID = mp.GLEntity 
        AND gl_entries_for_month.AccountNo IN ('18125','18130') 
       THEN DebitAmount - CreditAmount 
       ELSE 0 
    END) AS [TEST]
```